# Where does contacts leads captured in Joomla contacts component

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

I am having one doubt about the contacts component in Joomla. I have used this component in my website. After that I found that whenever I have submitted the details, Mail will be generated and send it that user who have submitted. So I have two question now.

1. Where does this information get saved and how can I manage leads.
2. How can I edit the email which is sending to user after submitting the details.

Hope I make my self clear. If some one have any suggestion about that please help.

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

With the default Joomla contact component, the only details that get saved to the database are the contact details, which you manually add yourself in the backend. After sending an email, this information doesn't get saved in the database, it send and that's it, therefore you cannot manage any leads.

As your your second question, if I understand you correctly, then this basically gets answered in my first point above.

You might be best off having a look at the [Contact Forms](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/contact-forms) and [Help Desk](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/clients-a-communities/help-desk) categories on the Joomla Extensions Directory.

Hope this helps

Comment: Okay, So is there any plugin for that which will have that kind of functionality so I can captured the information, of the person who submitted the details on the site. Or I need to make custom plugin. Or use any of the third party plugin you have suggested?

Answer (score 0):

In general core Joomla contacts component doesn't store submitted info anywhere. It just gathers data and send it via e-mail to you, and the person who submitted form (if he checks to get a copy of contact).

Also e-mail content cannot be overwritten without editing Joomla core files (which makes it non update proof solution, which means after Joomla update you can loose all changes you've done).

You can edit layout of email sent in **components/com_contact/controllers/contact.php** file, method name **_sendEmail**, or if you just wan't to change texts: **languages/YOUR_LANGUAGE/LANG_PREFIX_com_contact.ini**

If you want more functionality, You might consider using Third Party contact form.

Comment: Why would you edit the file rather than use a language override?

Comment: In language override you can only edit title, and pre-text, but cannot add additional info, change it's layout, etc.

Comment: Sure I'm just saying if all you wnat to do is change the message and title just do the override, don't mess around in the ini file the way you have suggested.